# dynamically import a React Component if that file exists, otherwise show a default message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, eslint

I want to conditionally import a React Component if the file exists and if not do something else. For example show a default view or message.

I tried this:

```js
let Recipe;
try {
  Recipe = require(`docs/app/Recipes/${props.componentName}`);
} catch (e) {
  Recipe = () => <div>Not found</div>;
}
```

However the linter is complaining that I should not try to dynamicaly require a file, but use a string literal instead.

Is there a cleaner approach to to what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is this approach is that it kills bundle optimizations and includes all files from `docs/app/Recipes/` into a bundle, even if they aren't used.

A better way to write this is to use `<React.Suspense>` and `React.lazy`:

```
const Recipe = React.lazy(() =>
  import(`docs/app/Recipes/${props.componentName}`)
  .catch(() => ({ default: () => <div>Not found</div> }))
);
```

Which is used as:

```
<React.Suspense fallback={'loading...'}><Recipe/></React.Suspense>
```

A cleaner way to do this and avoid linter error is to have a map of possible components:

```
import Foo from 'docs/app/Recipes/Foo';
import Bar from 'docs/app/Recipes/Bar';
...

const componentsMap = { Foo, Bar };

...

const Recipe = componentsMap[props.componentName] || () => <div>Not found</div>;
```

In this case `props.componentName` can be validated if needed.

Answer (score 5):

in fact there is. With the recent release of React v16.6.0 "[lazy code splitting](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactlazy-code-splitting-with-suspense)" was introduced. This is how it works, it makes sense to use it together with reacts' 'suspense':

```
 import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
 const Recipe = lazy(() =>import(`./docs/app/Recipes/${props.componentName}`));

    function SomeComponent() {
      return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
          <Recipe />
        </Suspense>
      );
    }
```

To handle the case that the component isn't found you can use [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#error-boundaries). You would wrap your component with it like this:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
    <Recipe />
  </Suspense>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Best you read more about it directly on the react docs I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I have been troubled by this problem all afternoon, and now I have solved it:

If "../views/dev/dev.tsx" exists, import it, otherwise import '../views/not-found/not-found'

```
const requireCustomFile = require.context('../views/dev/', false, /dev.tsx$/);
let Dev = React.lazy(() => import('../views/not-found/not-found'));
if (requireCustomFile.keys()?.length) {
  const keys: string[] = requireCustomFile.keys();
  if (keys.includes('./dev.tsx')) {
    const str = '/dev';
    Dev = React.lazy(() => import(`../views/dev${str}`));
  }
}
```

if `dev.tsx` not exit :

```
// ⬇️webpack report an error: Can't resolve module
import(`../views/dev/dev.tsx`)) 

// ⬇️webpack will not report an error until the load the module
const str = '/dev';
import(`../views/dev${str}`)
```